# Define new personalized Claim in XO

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5, experience-optimization

We have a Test environment of SDL Web 8.5 with XO and XPM configured. Everything works fine except the personalized claims. We configured the triggers, and added the claims into the session content service and the application (into the cd_ambient_conf.xml), and made a jar which makes a put into the claim store of a new claim but it doesn't work.

Do I forgot some configuration in any service?

Thanks you.

Comment: Did you define a prefix for the root of your claim URI, in smarttarget_conf.xml?

Comment: @PeterKjaer we have defined into the session content service and into the app

Comment: Okay. And have you added the new claims to the ForwardedClaims and GloballyAcceptedClaims in cd_ambient_conf.xml for your website and content service respectively?